# Дробное число разделить

Tags: python

имеется дробное число, например 2,5
Как 2 засунуть в одну переменную, а 0,5 сделать пятёркой и засунуть в другую?
Может есть такая функция у кого поделитесь? Или объясните как написать.

Comment: `print(str(2.5).split('.'))`

Comment: а 0.005 как записать тогда? тоже как 5?

Answer (score 0):

вот так:

```
n = 2.5
a, b = [int(el) for el in str(n).split(".")]
```